# Can't install mod_wsgi via yum on CentOS v8

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi

I was following this [article](https://dev.to/sm0ke/flask-deploy-with-apache-on-centos-minimal-setup-2kb7) (on dev.to) on how to deploy `Flask` with `Apache` on `CentOS`, then I got an error.  I wasn't able to install `mod_wsgi` via `yum` on my machine running `CentOS v8`:

```
$ sudo yum install mod_wsgi
No match for argument: mod_wsgi
Error: Unable to find a match: mod_wsgi
```

How do I get past this error ?  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

refer to the official `mod_wsgi` documentation on `pypi`
https://pypi.org/project/mod-wsgi/

> The second way of installing mod_wsgi is to install it **as a Python package** into your Python installation using the Python **pip install** command. This can be used on all platforms, including Windows.

```
$ pip install mod_wsgi
```

install `mod_wsgi` **globally**, meaning **deactivate** first the current virtual environment of your `Flask` app.

Comment: Some additional steps that were needed for a cpanel CentOS setup: `sudo yum install python3 python3-devel ea-apache24-devel` and then it works with `sudo pip3 install mod_wsgi` .